# Strange Xamarin Forms Build Error for Android Project

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I have seen a few questions about this error here on SO, but none pertaining to Xamarin Forms and VS2017, so this is not a duplicate.

I have a simple little project that demonstrates the rare use of constructors in XAML. I am getting the following build error:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

The error occurs in the file `<project-name>/C`, and my code contains zero references to this resource.

I am using a totally fresh re-install of VS2017, only now upgraded to v15.5.1, and have done nothing except delete an emulator left over from my previous installation that was not starting. I'm currently using the default `Android_Accelerated_x86_Nougat (Android 7.1 API 25)` emulator that was installed as part of the VS2017 install. I have made zero configuration changes in VS yet, this is straight 'out the box'.

The `Xamarin Diagnostics` 'mode' in the Output Window is empty, as no attempt has yet been made to deploy the app, because it won't build.

What can I look at and do about this?

Comment: Could you upload it to GitHub?

Comment: @MatPag Sure, it's here: https://github.com/bradykelly/xamlforms.git

I've ignored `packages`, `obj`, and `bin`, as I have very limited bandwidth, but Nuget will prompt you top restore the packages.

Comment: I've compiled your project in my workspace and everything is working fine without any change... Maybe you have some corrupted libraries or packages because i can't think to anything else

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, @MatPag. I'll be spending today troubleshooting further.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the project from scratch in my new install of VS and now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @MatPag Thanks, it's been such a battle to get any Android setup going, and now I'm finally there and can start learning.